# Деграда[Н]т/дегенерат [Разница]

Tags: терминология

Деградант - унизительный, позорный.
Дегенерат - человек с отклонением в развитии, социализации. 
А каково значение слова "Деградат" в таком случае, ежели оно вообще существует в терминологии.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Точнее, *деградант* (от лат. gradus - ступень) дословно *спускающийся по ступеням* или просто *опустившийся*.

*Дегенерат* (от гр. genоs - род) - *вырожденец*, *выродок*.

Латинский суффикс *-nt-* характерен для действительных причастий, *-t-* - для страдательных. Например, *адресат* - получатель почтового отправления, *адресант* - отправитель.

Следовательно, *деградант* - это тот, кто деградирует сам, а *деградат* некий объект или результат деградации. Хотя лично мне такого слова не встречалось...

Answer (score 0):

Наверное, нет такого слова.

Comment: Был вопрос по поводу слова "деградат". Нет такого слова